# How can I add 'Font Awesome' to my app with twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails: Using Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome)

I have Rails app in which I'm using many twitter-bootstrap's icon.

For that I did put "boostrap.css.erb" in /assets/stylesheets/ folder directly
also "glyphicons-halflings-white.png" and "glyphicons-halflings.png" in /assets/images/ folder directly.

Now I just downloaded Font awesome and extracted.
I'm guessing I have to do something with these files. Can anyone tell me how to set up?

**/css/**  folder

- font-awesome-ie7.min.css
- font-awesome.css
- font-awesome.min.css

**/font/**  folder

- fontawesome-webfont.eot
- fontawesome-webfont.svg
- fontawesome-webfont.ttf
- fontawesome-webfont.woff
- FontAwesome.otf

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just add your stylesheets to the head section of your html

```
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <![endif]-->
```

And make sure you put all the font files in the same folder (I used /css as an example). Then to use the icons on a page, just do

```
<span class='icon-star'></span>
```

(that inserts the icon using the css in the font-awesome.css file. Check there for all the possible classes. There's a bunch like icon-gear, icon-star, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is that I'm using rails. It has its own convention and it's not piece of cake

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I was under the assumption Rails was a backend scripting language and still used html/css for the front-end.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253146/font-face-rails-3-2/12253606#12253606

Comment: Follow the instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772507/ruby-not-load-font-awesome