# ruby not load font-awesome

Tags: ruby, font-awesome

i am trying to load font-awesome to my view

I have read other answers and implement the [Rails: Using Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052398/rails-using-font-awesome)

What i have done

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'


    # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
    # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
    Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

    module Blog
      class Application < Rails::Application
        # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
        # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
        # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

        # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
        # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
        # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

        # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
        # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
        # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

        config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
      end
    end
```

I have rename the font-awesome.min.css to font-awesome.min.css.erb and use assets_path

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';
 src:url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3") %>');
 src:url('<%= asset_path("awesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3") %>') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3") %>') format('woff'),
 url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3") %>') format('truetype'),
 url('<%= asset_path("fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregula") %>') format('svg');
 font-weight:normal;font-style:normal}
```

and load the css file on the view

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap.css' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'animate.css' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'font-awesome.min.css' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'font.css' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'app.css' %>
```

and on Chrome the font files are not loaded

and on server i get

```
Started GET "/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-14 08:36:37 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Please help

Comment: you should put your fonts folder inside the `app\assets\css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to integrate font-awesome to rails is via [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem. It will integrate font-awesome to rails asset pipeline.

In your Gemfile add

```
gem "font-awesome-rails"
```

and run  `bundle install`  to install the gem

Then in your scss file import it using

```
@import "font-awesome";
```

That's it! Now you can use it in your view as

```
<i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
```

If you prefer to use css instead of scss then add the require statement in your application.css

```
*= require font-awesome
```

### Update

If you don't want to use font-awesome-rails gem then follow the steps

1. Place your fonts in the folder app/assets/fonts
2. In config/application.rb add the following lines

   ```
   # Add fonts path
   config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

   # Precompile additional assets
   config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
   ```
3. Declare your font in font-awesome.css.erb like

   ```
   @font-face {
      font-family:'FontAwesome';
      src:    font-url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
      src:    font-url('fontawesome-webfont?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      font-url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      font-url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      font-url('fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
      font-weight:normal;
      font-style:normal;
   }
   ```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i know that but i have to implement the way i already have.Thanks for your answer