# asset_path - fonts not applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, jruby

I am trying to load some additional fonts in my rails application using:

1. Jruby 1.7.3
2. Rails 3.2.13

The css (its type is css.scss.erb) document is in *app/assets/stylesheets/custom/* folder and looks like follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('<%= asset_path('/fonts/Lato-Light.woff') %>') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('<%= asset_path('/fonts/Lato-Regular.woff') %>') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url('<%= asset_path('/fonts/Lato-Bold.woff') %>') format('woff');
}
```

The fonts file are in application *lib/assets/fonts* folder. I have added the following line in my *application.rb* file:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('lib', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

I am not getting an request error, so I suppose that my fonts are rendered in the web page but they are not applied. That's the path that the *asset_path* method generates in the result css file:

[image]

Has anyone idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have a look at this to setup @fontface in rails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253146/font-face-rails-3-2/12253606#12253606

Comment: @Richlewis thanks I found the solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have read from Rails 3.1:

> The public folder is no longer the supported place for CSS, images and
>   fonts, instead they live in the app/assets/* and vendor/assets/*
>   folders.

So, to set up new fonts, I have followed the steps below:

1. download the desire font from http://www.google.com/fonts
2. convert each file -
   http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
3. copy all *.eot, *.svg, *.ttf, *.woff files in /vendor/assets/fonts
   folder
4. create fonts.css.scss file in the /assets/stylesheets/custom/ folder
   as         follows:

> ```
> @font-face {
>
> font-family: 'RobotoCondensed';
> src: asset-url('robotocondensed-regular-webfont.eot', 'font');
> src: asset-url('robotocondensed-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix', 'font') format('embedded-opentype'),
> asset-url('robotocondensed-regular-webfont.woff', 'font') format('woff'),
> asset-url('robotocondensed-regular-webfont.ttf', 'font') format('truetype'),
> asset-url('robotocondensed-regular-webfont.svg#roboto_condensedbold','font') format('svg');
> font-weight: normal;
> font-style: normal;
> }
> ```

Source: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/09/26/serving-fonts-in-rails-3-1/